# removeEvents by className

Tags: fullcalendar

I am trying to user Full Calendars removeEvents function to remove a set of events with the same className. I don't think I am typing the syntax exactly right.

> $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.className===user);

this is part of an ajax script. When readyState == 4 this is the last bit of code that gets executed.

Currently it removes all Calendar entries. I know how to remove by ID but I don't think I am quite grasping the Filter string syntax. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass an ID **or** a filter function witn an event object as parameter.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', myRemove);

function myRemove(event) {
    return "user" === event.className; // ensure your events have this custom class !
}
```

[The docu](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/removeEvents/)